# calculate the transition probability matrix (1 and 2 order) for the occurrence of wet, dry and neutral spells during different seasons

Tags: markov-chain

I have a time series of dry, wet and neutral conditions for 4 seasons during 60 years (240 conditions). My data has text file format with 3 columns (year, season and rainfall conditions). How can I do markov chain by R. I want to calculate the transition probability matrix for the occurrence of wet, dry and neutral spells during different seasons. Please inform me about R commands are suitable for my need.

Comment: You have key words there (Markov chain, transition probability) you can use to search R documentation. Please (a) review guidance on software-related questions in the Help Center (b) don't come here without (apparently) trying basic searches for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You need the package `markovchain`. Consult http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/vignettes/an_introduction_to_markovchain_package.pdf and/or http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/markovchain.pdf .

For installing the package, you should type `install.package("markovchain")` . You need to install it only once.